# how can I fix the fe_sendauth: no password supplied error?

Tags: ruby, psql

This is my `database.yml` file.

I am trying to create database for a ruby app but the **error** always pops up

> "fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

Tried to `createuser - w --no-password` on the CLI ended up with the same error.

Any help to fix this please ?

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:

  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
  username: app
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: visit this previous response: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126176

Comment: cannot use alter